# Ionic Vue PWA - ios status bar color

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-vue

I am developing a PWA using Ionic Vue.
How can I change the color of the status bar in iOS?

I read [this doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/advanced) and tried writing `theme-color Meta` in the `<template>` tag, but it didn't change the color.

```html
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)" content="#3880ff" />
    <meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)" content="#eb445a" />
    <ion-content>...</ion-content>
  </ion-page>
</template>
```

[image]

Comment: The color comes from your primary color in the global.scss file, Change the color there if you want to change the header color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by changing Safari status bar color with theme-color meta in index.html.

```html
<head>
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#051829" />
</head>
```